# SharePoint 2010, filter Document Set in URL

Tags: 2010, search, filter, url, query

I'm trying to filter a document set in SharePoint 2010. For example, the URL to the main document library is

```
#1) http://uat/sites/dps/doc/Forms/folders.aspx
```

I would access a document set like this

```
#2) http://uat/sites/dps/doc/NIA/2015/5697
```

and SharePoint would convert the URL to

```
#3) http://uat/sites/dps/doc/Forms/Document%20Set/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=44956&FolderCTID=0x0120D52000E8F1321E9D126C4585795384715088E4&List=b167384e-d795-49f8-9460-f5eff2d9fb9e&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fdps%2Fdoc%2FNIA%2F2015%2F5697
```

If I filter it, this is what would be appended onto #3

```
&FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=title1
```

Is there anyway I can append this filter onto #2, sort of like this?

```
#4) http://uat/sites/dps/doc/NIA/2015/5697?FilterField1=Title&FilterValue1=title1
```